# convert year-doy to mdy

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert a column (or create a new one) which is year-day of year to m/d/y. Originally I had year and day-of-year as two separate columns, but I concatenated (paste) them together because I thought I would need the year included with the day of year because of leap years. I am not opposed to using an additional package such as `date`.

Here is my data:

```
dat <- structure(list(doy = c(320, 350, 309, 310, 328, 321, 301, 338, 
304, 304, 308), year = structure(1:11, .Label = c("2000", "2001", 
"2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", 
"2010"), class = "factor"), conc = c("2000-320", "2001-350", 
"2002-309", "2003-310", "2004-328", "2005-321", "2006-301", "2007-338", 
"2008-304", "2009-304", "2010-308")), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("doy", 
"year", "conc"))
```

And looks like:

```
   doy year     conc
1  320 2000 2000-320
2  350 2001 2001-350
3  309 2002 2002-309
4  310 2003 2003-310
5  328 2004 2004-328
6  321 2005 2005-321
7  301 2006 2006-301
8  338 2007 2007-338
9  304 2008 2008-304
10 304 2009 2009-304
11 308 2010 2010-308
```

-cherrytree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No additional packages necessary:

```
within(dat, dtime <- as.POSIXct(conc, format='%Y-%j'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this works.

```
as.Date( paste(as.character(dat$year), "-01-01",sep="")) + dat$doy - 1
```

Just adds the day of the year (minus one) to Jan 1 of the year.